# Асинхронный python

Tags: python, многопоточность, асинхронность, asyncio, системное-программирование

Всех с новым годом!
Как мы знаем, в фреймворке asyncio main loop работает в одном потоке. Когда мы вызываем неблокирующие задания, требующие некоторого времени на выполнение(например запрос к БД), то главный цикл переключается на другие задания(при наличии). Так вот, правильно ли я понимаю, что на уровне ОС "отложенные" задания ответвляются в отдельный поток? Если нет, то как они НЕ блокируют главный цикл, если они находятся с ним в одном потоке в ожидании получения результата?

Comment: Не в ожидании. Они записывают в event loop что-то вроде "если на таком-то сокете появятся данные - вызови меня, пожалуйста" и отдают управление, чтобы смогли поработать другие задания. Когда в таком-то сокете данные появятся, event loop снова запустит это задание, и оно снова поработает до следующего ожидания сокета или до завершения

Comment: С помощью неблокирующих сокетов, модуля select и оператора yield (yield from) можно написать свой собственный упрощённый аналог asyncio для практики

Comment: Спасибо, теперь понятно стало)